# how to use print syntax in awk to write content into file in ksh

Tags: shell, awk, ksh

```
#!/bin/sh
FILENAME=/test/test.txt
awk -F, '
{ 
    printf("    Code %s  %\047d\n",$1,$2) >> $FILENAME
    r[NR] = $1
    c[NR] = $3here
}
END {
    for(i = 1; i <= NR; i++) printf("  %s Record Count   %s\n", r[i],c[i]) >> $FILENAME
}' totalsum.txt
```

am trying to route the result of awk to file., but its not getting writing into file.. is there is any mistake in that syntax.

Comment: `>>` redirection is a shell feature. Put it outside the `awk` script.

Comment: Estan..yes when i used outside with printf its printing as expected

Comment: Morton.. am reading the input file content like 12,1455.00,2 and routing them to another outputfile.

Comment: making sense before awk.. i have added some content in a file so am redirecting morton..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`FILENAME` is a builtin awk variable. You got SLIGHTLY unlucky picking that as the name of the variable you want to hold your output file name but this is another reason not to use all-upper-case variable names unless you have a good reason to. You were also trying to use shell syntax to access variable contents (awk uses `var`, not `$var`).

```
outfile=/test/test.txt
awk -F, -v outfile="$outfile" '
{ 
    printf "    Code %s  %\047d\n",$1,$2 >> outfile
    r[NR] = $1
    c[NR] = $3
}
END {
    for(i = 1; i <= NR; i++) printf "  %s Record Count   %s\n", r[i],c[i] >> outfile
}' totalsum.txt
```

Are you SURE you want to use `>>` instead of `>` though?

Why do the output redirection inside awk instead of outside?

Comment: great Morton.. am just curious any chance to apply sort along with awk -F.. like this  sort -t "," -k1,1 .... am looking for sorting with first cloumn in the file,,sample input 123,12.50,1

Comment: i learned Mortan.. awk -F, -v outfile="$outfile" -v ts="$ts"  -v tc="$tc" -v sq="'" ' and printed like this .. printf("%14s Total Amount                 %" sq ".2f\n "," ",ts)